# Should I stress highlighted articles in my CV

Tags: funding, cv, faculty-application

Part of my research attracted some attention like:

- Nature research highlights
- Monthly DOE (Department of Energy, USA) highlights
- Institute newsletter (Is also read by other labs)
- Editors suggestions on paper (like PRL)

My question is should I mention those in my CV or publications list or not at all, since the former three are not written by me but only about my work and as such not my work to claim.

Background: I'm drafting my CV for a young investigator grant. My overall resume is solid but nothing that keeps you awake at night. Especially empty are the two sections: received grants and won scientific awards.